# Python: difference between two statements print(m) vs m

Tags: python, terminal, output

[image]

What is the difference between m and print(m)?

Answer (score 1):

`m` will display `repr(m)`

whereas

`print(m)` will display `str(m)`, if `stdout` is directed to the console.

Comment: Hi @Reblochon, thanks for the reply. I just verified this and found something strange. Why is the type(print(m)) result is 'NoneType'? Should it be str?